# Getting more precise timing control in Linux

Tags: c, linux, timing

I am trying to create a low-jitter multicast source for digital TV. The program in question should buffer the input, calculate the intended times from the PCR values in the stream and then send the packets at relatively precise intervals. However, this is not running on a RTOS, so some timing variance is expected.

This is the basic code (the relevant variables are initialized, I just omitted the code here):

```
while (!sendstop) { 
    //snip
    //put 7 MPEG packets in one UDP packet buffer "outpkt"
    //snip
      waittime = //calculate from PCR values - value is in microseconds
    //waittime is in the order of 2000 -> 2ms
              sleeptime=curtime;
              sleeptime.tv_nsec += waittime * 1000L;
                    sleeptime.tv_sec += sleeptime.tv_nsec / 1000000000;
                    sleeptime.tv_nsec %= 1000000000;
              while (clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &sleeptime, NULL) && errno == EINTR) {
                    printf("I");
              }       
              sendto(sck,outpkt,1316,0,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen);    //send the packet       
              clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&curtime);                            
}
```

However, this results in the sending being too slow (since there is some processing that also takes time), so the buffer fills up. So, I thought that I should get the difference between "sleeptime" (the time that should have been) and "curtime" (the actual time) and the subtract it from the future "waittime". This almost works, but now is a bit too fast and now I get an empty buffer.

My next idea was to multiply the difference by some value before subtracting it, like this (just above "while..."):

```
difn=curtime.tv_nsec-ostime.tv_nsec;
if (difn<0) difn+=1000000000; 
  sleeptime.tv_nsec = sleeptime.tv_nsec-(difn*difnc)/1000;  //difnc - adjustment
   if (sleeptime.tv_nsec<0) {
        sleeptime.tv_nsec+=1000000000;
        sleeptime.tv_sec--;
   }
```

However, different values of difnc work at different times of day, servers and so on. There needs to be some kind of automatic adjustment based on the operation of the program. The best I could figure out was to increment/decrement it every time the buffer is full or empty, however, this leads to slow cycles of "too fast" - "too slow". I tried to adjust the "difnc" value based on how full/empty the buffer is but that too just leads of "slow"-"fast" cycles.

How can I properly automatically derive the "difnc" value or is there some other method of getting a more precise timing than with just the "clock_nanosleep" function but without busy waits (the server has other things to do)?

Comment: You can use a timer to schedule the output, and reverse the process: do the output immediately timer triggers, then do processing for the next triggering after that.

Comment: @user3528438, I'll try this, thanks. I'll need to set the timer to a different value sometimes, but hopefully I can do that immediately after sending the packet.